# Saving shared_ptr in unordered_map - calls destructor immediately

Tags: c++

I'm writing a subscriber to a central connection handler to and from my websocket. It is a circular reference, because each subscriber needs to use the same connection handler object, which I solved with a weak_ptr. In my connection handler class, I have a function to add a subscriber:

```
template<typename T>
void ROSBridgeClient::addSubscriber(std::string topic, size_t buffer_size, std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<T>)> cb) 
{ 
  if (subscribers.find(topic) != std::end(subscribers)) 
  { 
    std::cout << "Not adding subscriber: subscriber with topic '" << topic << "\n"; 
    return; 
  }
  auto sub = std::make_shared<subscriber::RBCSubscriber<T>>(shared_from_this(), topic, ..., cb);
  subscribers[topic] = sub; 
}
```

where subscribers is a map

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::weak_ptr<subscriber::SubscriberBase>> subscribers;
```

`SubscriberBase` is the base class for `RBCSubscriber<T>`.

Now, more or less as soon as the `addSubscriber` function exits, the destructor for `RBCSubscriber<T>` is called. Am I misunderstanding the smart pointers? Why isn't the map "keeping alive" the pointer?

In an earlier version of the code, I returned the shared_ptr `sub` from the above example and "kept it alive" in my test class and everything worked. I'm just not sure why the destructor is called, even though the lifetime of the pointer isn't over, as it's saved in the map.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do. How was the object created to begin with? Present your [MCVE].

Answer (score 3):

From your code as I can see you are creating your `std::shared_ptr` under `addSubscriber` method and store `std::weak_ptr` in `std::unordered_map`. `std::weak_ptr` doesn't prolong lifetime. So as soon as you exit the method, your one and only strong reference -`sub`- which is on call stack, is destroyed.